# Nullable inout Constructor Creates Mutable Object

Tags: d

The following code gives me a strange error when trying to compile:

```
import std.conv: to;
import std.typecons;
import std.traits;

void main()
{
    alias BuiltinScalars = TypeTuple!(ubyte, byte, ushort, short, uint, int, ulong, long, 
                                      float, double, real, char, wchar, dchar, bool,
                                      ifloat, idouble, ireal, cfloat, cdouble, creal);

    foreach (T; BuiltinScalars)
    {
        foreach (ValT; BuiltinScalars)
        {
            alias KeyT = T;
            alias AAT = ValT[KeyT];
            foreach (NullableAAT; TypeTuple!(Nullable!AAT, const(Nullable!AAT), immutable(Nullable!AAT)))
            {
                NullableAAT naa;
                assert(naa.to!string() == "Nullable.null");

                static if (!isSomeString!KeyT)
                    enum KeyTInit = KeyT.init;
                else
                    enum KeyTInit = `""`;

                NullableAAT naav = [KeyTInit:ValT.init];
                assert(naav.to!string() == '[' ~ KeyTInit.to!string() ~ ':' ~ ValT.init.to!string() ~ ']');
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

I have no idea what the problem is with this code. Nullable has only one constructor, with the signature `this(inout T value) inout`.

The strange thing (or maybe not strange. It could be that the compiler just gives up after so many errors) is that the error is not present for all combinations of types, just those that have ubyte as a key type. The complete error output is:

```
bug.d(46): Error: inout constructor std.typecons.Nullable!(ubyte[ubyte]).Nullable.this creates mutable object, not immutable
bug.d(46): Error: inout constructor std.typecons.Nullable!(byte[ubyte]).Nullable.this creates mutable object, not immutable
bug.d(46): Error: inout constructor std.typecons.Nullable!(ushort[ubyte]).Nullable.this creates mutable object, not immutable
bug.d(46): Error: inout constructor std.typecons.Nullable!(short[ubyte]).Nullable.this creates mutable object, not immutable
bug.d(46): Error: inout constructor std.typecons.Nullable!(uint[ubyte]).Nullable.this creates mutable object, not immutable
bug.d(46): Error: inout constructor std.typecons.Nullable!(int[ubyte]).Nullable.this creates mutable object, not immutable
bug.d(46): Error: inout constructor std.typecons.Nullable!(ulong[ubyte]).Nullable.this creates mutable object, not immutable
bug.d(46): Error: inout constructor std.typecons.Nullable!(long[ubyte]).Nullable.this creates mutable object, not immutable
bug.d(46): Error: inout constructor std.typecons.Nullable!(float[ubyte]).Nullable.this creates mutable object, not immutable
bug.d(46): Error: inout constructor std.typecons.Nullable!(double[ubyte]).Nullable.this creates mutable object, not immutable
bug.d(46): Error: inout constructor std.typecons.Nullable!(real[ubyte]).Nullable.this creates mutable object, not immutable
bug.d(46): Error: inout constructor std.typecons.Nullable!(char[ubyte]).Nullable.this creates mutable object, not immutable
bug.d(46): Error: inout constructor std.typecons.Nullable!(wchar[ubyte]).Nullable.this creates mutable object, not immutable
bug.d(46): Error: inout constructor std.typecons.Nullable!(dchar[ubyte]).Nullable.this creates mutable object, not immutable
bug.d(46): Error: inout constructor std.typecons.Nullable!(bool[ubyte]).Nullable.this creates mutable object, not immutable
bug.d(46): Error: inout constructor std.typecons.Nullable!(ifloat[ubyte]).Nullable.this creates mutable object, not immutable
bug.d(46): Error: inout constructor std.typecons.Nullable!(idouble[ubyte]).Nullable.this creates mutable object, not immutable
bug.d(46): Error: inout constructor std.typecons.Nullable!(ireal[ubyte]).Nullable.this creates mutable object, not immutable
bug.d(46): Error: inout constructor std.typecons.Nullable!(cfloat[ubyte]).Nullable.this creates mutable object, not immutable
bug.d(46): Error: inout constructor std.typecons.Nullable!(cdouble[ubyte]).Nullable.this creates mutable object, not immutable
bug.d(46): Error: inout constructor std.typecons.Nullable!(creal[ubyte]).Nullable.this creates mutable object, not immutable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The associative array literal is, by default, mutable.

To fix, you can replace:

```
            NullableAAT naav = [KeyTInit:ValT.init];
```

with:

```
            alias CAA = typeof(naa.get());
            CAA aa = [KeyTInit:ValT.init];
            NullableAAT naav = aa;
```

This will declare the AA with the correct constness, which will propagate to the `Nullable` via the constructor's `inout`.

> The strange thing (or maybe not strange. It could be that the compiler just gives up after so many errors) is that the error is not present for all combinations of types, just those that have ubyte as a key type.

Yes, it stops after the first iteration of the second loop. You can test by removing types from the head of your tuple.

Comment: I guess, then, that AAs do not yet benefit from uniqueness inference? Or is it due to something else that the literals cannot be inferred as const, immutable, etc.?

Comment: It's not special about AAs - your code expects the constness to propagate all the way from the variable declaration, through the Nullable inout constructor, and down to the AA. In reality, the propagation goes in the different direction: the constness of the constructor's parameters defines the constness of the constructed object.